# Display Message on same popup window

Tags: php, javascript

I want to display message on same customised popup window . Say for eg when i click on signin link a popup window comes and when i click on submit button , it get redirected to loginpage.php where php code for connection is written and other code of php is wriiten for database fetching . and if login credential match it get redirected to main page

So what i want to do is when some one click on signin link and popup window open up and when clicked on submit button , if the credential dont match it should throw error on same popup window before it closes

Comment: jquery ajax. Probably want to use some sort of modal window for the pop up. I like using shadowbox js

Answer (score 0):

Check jQuery's UI stuff...

Demo of the std dialog (in which you can put forms etc etc) http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Specifically, this demo: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form